Image of a splitting of short exact sequence of vector bundles is a subbundle
I am currently learning about principal $G$-bundles from Tu's Differential Geometry: Connections, Curvature and Characteristic Classes.
Proposition 27.20 of my edition states the following:
"Let $$ 0 \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{i} B \xrightarrow{j} C \rightarrow 0$$
be a short exact sequence of vector bundles over a manifold P. Then there is a one-to-one correspondence $$ \{ \text{ subbundles } H\subset B\ |\ B = i(A) \oplus H \} \leftrightarrow \{ \text{ splittings } k:C\rightarrow B\}."$$
While proving the result, Tu states the following:
"If $k:C \rightarrow B$ is a splitting, $k(C)$ is a subbundle of B."
I am lost as to why this is true. I think it is not true that given a general bundle map its image is a subbundle of the codomain vector bundle. Why is it true in this case?

Think about the rank of the map $k$.

@TedShifrin do you mean the following? By definition, $j \circ k = 1_C$, i.e. the identity on $C$. This implies that $k$ is an injective immersion, or an embedding. Thus $k(C)$ is an embedded manifold, or equivalently (thanks to the Constant Rank Theorem), a regular submanifold of $B$.

Well, I was thinking more about how to see $k(C)$ is locally trivial, but it should amount to the same thing.
